# How do I select all values in a table such that it satisfies 2 conditions?

Tags: sql

In an SQL schema suppose I have a table of such:

Table1:

| Solution | Use of Chemical | Type of Chemical |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | HCL | Acid |
| B | NaOH | Base |
| A | NaOH | Base |
| C | HCL | Acid |
| D | H2SO4 | Acid |
| E | LiOH | Base |
| A | KOH | Base |

If I made another table labelling the most common acid / base that was taken as a count from Table1:

Table2:

| Name | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HCL | acid | 2 |
| H2SO4 | acid | 1 |
| NaOH | base | 2 |
| LiOH | base | 1 |
| KOH | base | 1 |

How would I display all the Solutions that use **both** the most common acid and base?

In this example I would display "A" because it has both HCL (2 occurences) and NaOH (2 occurences).

Comment: Which Database you are using ?

Comment: @Tushar a custom one

Answer (score 0):

Distinctly counting for the type of the chemicals would resolve the issue.

Provided your DBMS supports Window/Analytic functions, you can use the following SELECT statement to return the desired result

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT Solution,
        COUNT(DISTINCT Type_of_Chemical) OVER (PARTITION BY Solution) AS cnt_acid_and_base
   FROM table1
)
SELECT Solution
  FROM t
 WHERE cnt_acid_and_base = 2 -- both "Acid" and "Base"
 GROUP BY Solution
```

or directly use a HAVING clause such that

```
 SELECT Solution
   FROM table1
  GROUP BY Solution  
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Type_of_Chemical)=2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RegGTaqQ)</kbd>